# Is it valid json (schema) to say that an element can be a single item or an array

Tags: json, jsonschema, rapidjson

Is it possible to specify that a particular json value can be either a single element or an array?

E.g. Can both of following json documents be valid according to a given single json schema.

```
"person": {
    "name": "john",
    "friends": "jack"
}

"person": {
    "name": "john",
    "friends": ["jack", "jill"]
}
```

It's certainly possible (I believe) if you ignore the concept of schema, and simply when you are parsing using a parser such as rapidjson, to simply check if the element is an array or not before reading the contents.

What I want to know is, if I take this approach, will it be a problem if I want to specify a json schema for it later on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON schema you can specify either *one* type that an item must match, or an array of types of which the item must match at least one (plus a few other possibilities).

So yes, you can have a schema that says the "friends" value is either a string, or an array of strings.

Obviously this means that client code and server code need to distinguish both cases and have different code for each case; you might consider sending an array with one string instead of someone has exactly one friend to simplify all code.

Comment: This is technically correct.  However, using an array of `type`s is discouraged for a couple reasons.  First, it can be difficult to read and maintain with constraints for different types mixed together in one schema.  Second, many validators don't handle this feature properly.  A better approach is to use `anyOf` or `oneOf`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, JSON Schema can express this using the `anyOf` or `oneOf` keywords.  These keywords specify an array of schemas.  `anyOf` is valid if one or more of the schemas are valid.  `oneOf` is valid if one and only one of the schemas is valid.  `anyOf` is almost always sufficient.

Here is a JSON Schema that would validate your example person object

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" }
    "friends": {
      "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/friend" },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/friend" }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "friend": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```