# anyOf of in json schema 04 which has object and array

Tags: jsonschema

I have to convert below example to json schema, My input can have employee details in an object or an array of objects. What could be the json schema.

```
{
  "id": "adadad123",
  "employee": [
    {
      "empid": 123,
      "name": "asdas"
    },
    {
      "empid": 323,
      "name": "asds"
    }
  ],
  "employee": {
    "empid": 323,
    "name": "asds"
  }
}
```

Comment: Formatting and tags

Comment: It could be anything. What are your constraints? What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it valid json (schema) to say that an element can be a single item or an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632245/is-it-valid-json-schema-to-say-that-an-element-can-be-a-single-item-or-an-arra)

Comment: @prasad Your example not valid JSON. If you fix that, it will be easier for us to help. You should also include in the question your best attempt at a schema.

Answer (score 1):

As per Jason's comments:

1. Yes, it is possible to say that a property may contain a single element or an array.
   There are multiple ways, but the `oneOf` keyword would be my recommendation.
2. The given JSON example is invalid as the same property is included twice.

---

Assuming those are two separate example instances:

```
{
  "id": "adadad123",
  "employee": [
    {
      "empid": 123,
      "name": "asdas"
    },
    {
      "empid": 323,
      "name": "asds"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
{
  "id": "adadad123",
  "employee": {
    "empid": 323,
    "name": "asds"
  }
}
```

Both of these could be described with a basic JSON Schema utilizing the `oneOf` keyword (not using `anyOf` since it cannot possibly be a single object AND an array at the same time).
It could look like this then:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "string" },
    "employee": {
      "oneOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/Employee" },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Employee" }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Employee": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "empId": { "type": "number" },
        "name": { "type": "string" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: As per the latest JSON Schema Draft 2019-09 the `definitions` keyword was renamed to `$defs` but both are supported still.